# Get the position of the iterator?? C++

Tags: c++, iterator

Need to do a check on whether the position is odd or even.

```
 for(auto a : aliens) {
  if(a - vec.begin() % 2 == 0){

   /*do something */ 
  }
```

guessing it would be something like that from what i have researched but cant seem to get it running which is rather annoying.
Thanks..

Comment: What is `aliens`? A std::vector?

Comment: Don't use for-ranged loop when you need that kind of condition inside.

Comment: if( (a - vec.begin()) % 2 == 0){

Comment: What is `aliens`? What is `vec`?

Comment: You could also keep a `bool` variable and flip it on every iteration.

Comment: Please provide a real code example, with all the required declarations.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee none of the iterators in aliens will ever be invalidated (and even then), better store indices instead. That will save you a whole lot of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach:

```
bool isEven = true;
for(auto a : aliens) {
  isEven = !isEven;
  if(isEven){

   /*do something */ 
  }
```

Comment: @r Shau Thanks, that approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot do it in this type of loop. This is `foreach` and `foreach` doesn't give you access to the iterators but to the itered objects themselves. You have to use `for` loop when you need access to the iterator.

Comment: How can you possibly know that `aliens` is not  container full of iterators?

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, you're right, I considered `vec.begin()` to be `aliens.begin()`.

Comment: Should have been more clear, its full of objects

Comment: @user3463583 Of course it is, but what type of objects?